# Get pixel channels from a Mat element in C++

Tags: java, c++, opencv

I have a java function I would like to recode in C++ to improve efficiency. Problem is I dont't know how to get the BRG values of a pixel in a Mat in C++.

Here is my java function :

```
private static Mat f_blanc(Mat A) {
    double c = 1.2;
    Size sz = A.size();
    Mat A1 = new Mat(sz, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < sz.width; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < sz.height; j++) {
            double b = A.get(j, i)[0];
            double g = A.get(j, i)[1];
            double r = A.get(j, i)[2];
            if (r < c * b || g < c * b) {
                A1.put(j, i, 255);
            }
        }
    }
    return A1;
}
```

Comment: Where does `Mat` come from? Is this opencv?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: yes, Mat is an OpenCV element

Comment: I don't know if it matters but which version of OpenCV is this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It depends on the type of the matrix. You can access the BRG values with

```
Vec3b& intensity = A.at<Vec3b>(j, i);
uchar& b = intensity.val[0];
uchar& g = intensity.val[1];
uchar& r = intensity.val[2];
```

for matrix type `CV_8U3` and integer values in the range [0, 255] or

```
Vec3f& intensity = A.at<Vec3d>(j, i);
double& b = intensity.val[0];
double& g = intensity.val[1];
double& r = intensity.val[2];
```

for matrix type `CV_64F3` double values in the range [0, 1].

These values are references. You can edit them by assigning values to them

```
b = 255;
```

Comment: It's working ! Thank you so much. By any chance, do you now how i could modify the value of a pixel (the C++ equivalent of the "put" function in java) ?

Comment: The functions return references. You can assign values to them.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Mat, you can use "data" member variable to access the data.

```
Mat img;
for( int h = 0; h < img.height; h++ )
{
 for( int w = 0; h < (img.width*3); w += 3 ) // if you have 3 channels
  {         
      int pos = h* img.width*3 + w*3;
      double b = img.data[pos];
      double g = img.data[pos+1];
      double r = img.data[pos+2];
  }
}
```

I did not compiled this one, use as a reference code and welcoming your comments